# No owin.Environment item was found in the context in asp mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, owin, asp.net-identity-2, katana

This is my code for register in identity :

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Register()
{
    var roles = db.Roles.Select(r => new { RoleID = r.Id, RoleName = r.Name }).ToList();
    ViewBag.Roles = new SelectList(roles, "RoleID", "RoleName");

    return View();
}

//
// POST: /Account/Register
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model, HttpPostedFileBase UserPhoto)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        model.DateRegister = DateTime.Now;
        var user = new ApplicationUser
        {
            UserName = model.UserName,
            Name = model.Name,
            Family = model.Family,
            PhoneNumber = model.PhoneNumber,
            Gender = model.Gender,
            BirthDay = model.BirthDay,
            DateRegister = model.DateRegister,
            IsActive = false,
            Email = model.Email
        };

        if (UserPhoto != null)
        {
            UserPhoto = Request.Files[0];
            var ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(UserPhoto.FileName);
            if (ext == ".jpeg" || ext == ".jpg" || ext == ".png")
            {

                string filename = model.PhoneNumber + ext;
                UserPhoto.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(@"~/Image/" + filename));
                user.UserPhoto = filename;
            }
        }

        var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {

            await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
            await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id,model.UserRoles);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        AddErrors(result);
    }


    return View(model);
}
```

WebConf :

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
  <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
  <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  <add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="false" />
  <add key="owin:AppStartup" value="Identity_Work.Startup" />
</appSettings>
```

But I get this error:

[image]

What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Check the `Startup.cs` most probably it can not be found

Comment: Also see if it works if you change `<add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="true" />`

Comment: And to be safe, include assembly name in `<add key="owin:AppStartup" value="Identity_Work.Startup, [Include assembly name here]" />`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on previous conversation you confirmed that

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Identity_Work.Startup))]
```

already exists in `Startup.cs`.

Which means that there is no longer a need for `owin:AppStartup` in the web.config.

Therefore your `appSettings` should look like this.

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="true" /> <!-- This should be true -->
</appSettings>
```

Comment: when i use thiss <appsetting> show me this error : `The ViewData item that has the key 'UserRoles' is of type 'System.String' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'.`

Comment: ok this is a new error. so at least the old issue is now fixed. This is an error associated with data you are passing between the controller and the view.

Comment: Looks like it has something to do with the dropdownlist.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I setup OAuth login before and had no idea it stopped working until today when I tried logging in XD. It works again!